# Variable with formatting text

Tags: java, tapestry

I have page (java / tml). I add to java class some variable `myVar` and add it to tml as: `${myVar}`. Page contain also other components: grid, textarea and etc.

At OnActivate() I define myVar. I generate myVar text as formatted text. So variable contain `<b>`, `</br>`, `&nbsp;`.

But at web page I see tags as text without formating. Can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OutputRaw](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/OutputRaw.html) solve me issue:

```
<t:outputraw value="myVar"/>
```